# url rewriting: I don't see index.html but a 404 error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I have the latest version of apache2 installed on my vm.

I activated the mod_rewrite by doing:

```
a2enmod rewrite
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now I just tested a little rule but it does not work.
I have a .htaccess and an index.htmlon my website root. The .htaccess contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.bla$ index.html [L]
```

But when I go to my_vm_ip/index.bla I don't see index.html but a 404 error !

Comment: Since you have full control over your server I suggest enabling rewrite debugging (`RewriteLoglevel 9`) and checking rewrite log -- it should tell you hat is going on. Another possible reason -- .htaccess files are not allowed by Apache configuration -- you need to apply `AllowOverride All` to website folder -- please check Apache manual for aforementioned directives.

Comment: I just added at the end of apache2.conf :

Comment: <Directory />
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>

But that changes nothing :(

Comment: So .. what the rewrite log says?

Comment: Absolutely nothing ... In the error.log I just have the file not found error.

Comment: This most likely means that .htaccess is not used. 1) Add `RewriteLog path/to/rewrite.log` to your server config -- maybe it writes to some other location; 2) Ensure (double check) that mod_rewrite is actually loaded; 3) Move your rewrite rules from .htaccess into `<VirtualHost>` context

Comment: 1) Done. But still 0 byte after a 404 in my browser.
2) The module is in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.
3) How to do that ?

Comment: 3) Well -- at least place them in server config, should work: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule  4) I do not know what distro you are using, but maybe Apache does not actually use that config file (wrong location) -- can you check this moment as well (if you do some major change in config (or breaking that config file on purpose) do you see the difference (error message like unable to start Apache etc)?? 5) Do you actually have index.html and it is not empty? (I know -- stupid question to ask at this stage).

Comment: 3) in a <Directory> ? 4) I'm on Debian 5.0 5) It is not empty :)

Comment: For the 3) I put it on a <Directory /> in apache2.conf, but still does not work. And in error.log I have still a "File not found bla.html" error.

Comment: `bla.html`?? Your rule is for `index.bla` -> `index.html`. In your .htaccess - can you define `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` and create 404.html file -- at least this will show you if .htaccess is working in general. Other than that -- I'm not a Linux guy to tell the difference between distros (how they work). **So far** it looks like either .htaccess does not work at all (gets ignored .. or has different name: `AccessFileName` directive) .. or mod_rewrite is not enabled. P.S. You can also try `[R=302,L]` instead of just `[L]` -- url will change in browser if it works -- easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

you probably meant `^index\.bla$` and if you go directly to my_vm_ip/index.html do you see the page? if not you probably are lacking the rights for the file